# Unable to set build configuration to x64 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In one project's Properties | Build tab, only x86 is available for Platform. The x64 build option is missing. This is occurring in one project of a solution. The other projects are all still using x64. I tried creating an entirely new and separate solution/project and it is also only displays x86. Also, in the General section x64 is available and selected for Platform Target.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Just create another solution build...

Comment: I tried that; it didn't work but thanks for your help. I fixed it in Configuration Manager simply by typing in x64. I mistakenly thought VS2010 would automatically know it was available since it was already available in Platform Target (in the project's Properties).

Comment: The config option should be available in the dropdowns. But I guess you can always set it manually if targetting .NET.